# how to test a class in phpunit, using the class itself or a mock?

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I am about to test some classes in a PHP/Laravel project, but I would like to give a simple example to try to explain my question:

I have a class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Sum
{
    public function sum($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

}
```

Then in my phpunit tests I have this:

```
$sum = new Sum;
$this->assertEquals(2, $sum->sum(1,1));
```

This test is working.

Now I am trying to do a test with mockery

```
$sum = \Mockery::mock(Sum::class);
$sum->shouldReceive('sum')->andReturn(2);
$this->assertEquals(2, $sum->sum(1,1));
```

This test is not working,but I am not quite sure if the first test is the best choice, which test should I use? or in which scenarios should I use mockery. thanks.

Comment: So, the first scenario is correct, the second one is not, because you are literally saying "_if someone calls `sum`, do return `2`_" and  then you assert if `sum` is returning `2`, so in that case you are testing if `Mockery` works, instead of your stuff